# Computing the density function of max of two items.

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ be exponentially distributed with mean $3$. Then how do we compute the density function of $max\{X,2\}$?

Comment: This RV takes a value of 2 with probability $P(X\leq 2)$. The density function for values greater than 2 looks the same as for the exponentially distributed variable.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the first argument. Could you explain how the second statement hold?

Comment: For values greater than two, the density function the same as the density function for $X$ because $\text{max}\{X,2\}=X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z = \max(X,2)$. We calculate $P(Z > c)$. If $c < 2$, this is clearly $1$. If $c \geq 2$, then $Z=X$ so this is just $P(X > c)$.

This specifies the CDF of $Z$ (by $P(Z \leq c) = 1- P(Z>c)$). Now, differentiate it, and put a point mass at the jump at $2$ based on the height of the jump in the CDF.

Comment: Why $Z\leq{2}$? If $X$ is more than 2 then $Z$ will be bigger than 2.

Comment: misread the question - fixed